# Angular 2 multiple components with the same selector

Tags: angular

How do you deal with the following situation where two components use the same selector? (removed the word "Component" to avoid clutter):

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Person as Person1 } from './person1';
import { Person as Person2 } from './person2';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<person1???></person1><person2???></person2>',
  directives: [Person1, Person2]
})
export class App {

}
```

person1.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'person',
  template: '<h1>Person 1</h1>'
})
export class Person {

}
```

person2.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'person',
  template: '<h1>Person 2</h1>'
})
export class Person {

}
```

This isn't a problem with React since you'd just use `<Person1 />` and `<Person2 />`

Comment: why you use selector: 'person' in both cases? It will'not work because you haven't this elements (<person1> and <person1>)

Comment: You can add two elements with the same selector imperatively using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 You could also add them declaratively if you wrap each of your `<person>` component in a different wrapper component.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Günter Zöchbauer comment you can add a bunch of boilerplate to accomplish this and wrap the components:

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Person as Person1 } from './person1';
import { Person as Person2 } from './person2';

@Component({
  selector: 'person1',
  template: '<person></person>',
  directives: [Person1]
})
export class Person1Wrapper {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'person2',
  template: '<person></person>',
  directives: [Person2]
})
export class Person2Wrapper {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<person1></person1><person2></person2>',
  directives: [Person1Wrapper, Person2Wrapper]
})
export class App {

}
```

Comment: directives no longer supported.